# Import from Excel to MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-2010, ms-project

First the problem:
I am simply trying to export an MS Project plan to excel and then import it back into project. Everything works fine for the most part (I create a mapping with primary key based on the task IDs). However, if I have a task that has lets say 20% in the % complete field, upon import MS Project marks it as 100% complete.  When I look at the export, it contains .2000000001 in the % complete field I've tried changing it to .2, 20%, etc., but I don't think this field even makes a difference.

I believe the problem is that there is an Actual Start Date with a date value, but the Finish Date is 12:00:00 AM (the same as other actuals with no value).  For some reason MS Project adds in an actual finish date to match the planned finish date.  If I change the value to 0, blank, or ‘NA’, it doesn’t pull the actual start date and marks the task as 0% complete. 
I’m thinking that the % complete values aren’t actually imported and just calculated based off the actual dates.  Any help or explanation would be appreciated!

Background on what I'm trying to do, in case anyone has any better ideas of how to go about this:
My team has a SharePoint list that we use to track deliverables.  Within this list there are Planned and Actual dates of different types of reviews (peer, team lead, sign-off).  I want to create a mapping between these list items, take an Excel extract of this list, take an Excel extract of the project plan, update the task completion percentages with VBA, and then import the excel project plan back into MS project.

(BTW, all software is 2010 version)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you need to export the project tasks to excel including, at least, the actual duration, unique task ID, and % complete fields.  It is preferable to do this programmatically so that you can include a formula in the excel workbook so that changing your % complete will properly update the actual duration. Then, import the task list back into project.

When importing:

1. Merge the tasks
2. Make unique task ID the key
3. Only import the actual duration

Your % complete is calculated based off the actual duration, so it should now be updated.